# Closed set is $F_{\sigma}$ and open set is $G_{\delta}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $(X,d)$ a metric space with $A \subseteq X$ closed and $B \subset X$.
>
> Prove that:
>
> a) $A$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set;
>
> b) $B$ is open if and only if $B$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

The approach I was thinking of involves writing $A$ as a countable reuniun of closed sets and $B$ as a countable intersection of open sets, but I'm not sure how to write the detailed proofs with explanations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second statement is not correct (any closed set in a metric space is $G_\delta$, and in general there will be plenty of sets which are $G_\delta$ but neither open nor closed).

Answer (score 1):

If $A_n=A$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, then $A_n$ is closed and $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$. A similar argument shows that, if $B$ is open, then $B$ is a countable intersection of open sets.